# X frame options error in Mozilla and IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mozilla

I m using object tag with type application/pdf
It is working with chrome but for Mozilla and IE I am facing x frame options error is there any options handling from front-end.

Comment: You've used the tag [tag:mozilla] but it says DO NOT USE THIS TAG. Mozilla is a company. The browser they make these days is called Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The point of X-Frame-Options is to allow whoever owns the content to decide if it can be shown in a frame or not.

If client-side code could override that, then it would be worthless, and anyone could turn off the limit and display the content on their own site.

Comment: Based on api URL PDF, I am getting PDF file that PDF I am showing In object tag for PDF viewer, do I need to make anything in back-end api allowing x frame?

Comment: The server *hosting the PDF* needs to **not** set X-Frame-Options